# How to manage Kubernetes Helm Chart Configurations?

Tags: git, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to set up a Kubernetes Cluster with multiple Helm Charts installed. I like the idea of having configurations versioned in an Git repository. I'm wondering if there is any tool (or recommended/best practice) of how the state of installed helm charts can be "versioned".

For example, I would like to have a yaml file similar to the following example with multiple helm charts and a tool (that's the tool I'm searching for) which will take care of applying this file to my Kubernetes cluster:

```
- name: gitlab
  chart: gitlab/gitlab-runner
  repository: https://charts.gitlab.io
  values:
    - gitlab-runner/values.yaml
    - local/gitlab-runner-override.yaml
  namespace: gitlab-runner

- name: metallb
  chart: stable/metallb
  values:
    - metallb/configuration.yaml

...
```

This way it is possible to manage the contents of the Kubernetes cluster in a programatically way.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) is the solution you need:

> Helmfile is a declarative spec for deploying helm charts. It lets
>   you...
>
> Keep a directory of chart value files and maintain changes in version
>   control. Apply CI/CD to configuration changes. Periodically sync to
>   avoid skew in environments.

You can read more about it in [this](https://medium.com/@naseem_60378/helmfile-its-like-a-helm-for-your-helm-74a908581599) article.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, I think you can create a new helm chart, lets say custom-app. Add all the other helm charts as a dependency.

Essentially, create a directory called `chart/` inside the helm directory of your new custom app and add the charts to it.

This is one way you could version a collection of charts.

Comment: This approach doesn't work well if you have two services that depend on the same "kind" of data store (both depend on the `stable/mysql` chart, say) but expect that they'll have independent copies of it; Helm will only install each chart once within a release.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think that you can use [dependency alias](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#alias-field-in-dependencies) for that case.